# Delay in first time Android app launch

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I am facing an issue with Android Studio build. When I create a build for any app, the app takes 8-10 sec to launch on first time and then works smoothly.This is not just when launched from IDE even when installed with apk file it launch with a delay. I tried creating build on different systems but mine has this issue. I am not sure this issue is with Android Studio or System preferences. I am using Android Studio 2.1 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Post ur onCreate and onStart method,

Comment: Cold starts http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Comment: Maybe you'd want to take a trace using the facility in https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview-walkthru.html and check what takes that much time in the loading.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. I also wanted to Ask a question on this..

Comment: Before the latest AS update.. The build was smooth enough for the first and launch the splash screen on icon click.. But now it takes a lot of Time to even the splash screen to appear .. I get a black screen instead befr showing splash screen.. And takes a lot of space in the cache . if you see in the app section

Comment: @sush I dont think this concerns the code in onCreate and onStart as every app has this problem and same code run smooth on other system..

Comment: @Piyush Thanks a lot. The provided link helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Profiler to check what is happening with CPU/Memory when the performance drops occurs. Get Android Studio 3 and check your app with Android Profiler https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler